# Triggering background task during Modern Standby mode

Tags: uwp, background-task

Is it possible to trigger a background task during modern standby mode?. I want to create a network trigger in a UWP application which will trigger when network is not available and it should work even in Modern Standby mode. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Derive from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/integrating-apps-with-modern-standby#microsoft-store-apps), background task can run in Modern standby mode. Please refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task) to create and register background task.

For network connection status, you could use specified trigger named NetworkStateChange in [SystemTriggerType enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.SystemTriggerType?view=winrt-19041) to trigger task.

Comment: Hello Arya, Thank you for your reply. Is there anyway I can use time trigger during modern standby mode. The scenario is network trigger will awake when no internet is available and will register a time trigger which will trigger after 5 min.

Comment: You mean that you want to trigger a background task five minutes after losing the connection, right?

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, I am confused whether timer trigger will trigger during modern standby mode.

Comment: What you need to consider is that timetrigger takes at least 15 minutes to trigger. It is not recommended to use timetrigger.

Comment: I think I can work with that. But I wonder if it works during modern standby mode. Because when I tried with sample app, It did not work.

Comment: Modern standby would only affect the foreground tasks, which will not affect a TimerTrigger. It will run as expected and if you add the following capabilities the background task will run uninterrupted.

Comment: <rescap:Capability Name="extendedExecutionUnconstrained"/>  and
 <rescap:Capability Name="extendedBackgroundTaskTime"/>

Comment: Thanks for the information Arya. But regarding timer trigger running in modern standby, I have tested with lid closed in my laptop, it did not work and started working just after I opened the lid. Thats, why I am confused. Maybe I am not using timer trigger properly, I have tried to check sample code from Microsoft UWP sample code repo but that did not work. Can you direct me towards any helpful resource?

Comment: This was the sample I have used,
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft official document many things work in modern standby but many things does not work too. Timer trigger background task is one of them.  If we register timer trigger background task in modern standby then it does not execute after 15 minute or 30 minute. Even BI activator activates it but the timer trigger background task does not execute in modern standby.  Works fine when device is awake. Tested many times in modern standby supported device.